# Set scroll viewer to automatically scroll to the bottom

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mytoolkit

I Used mytoolkit.extended controls for datagrid, there is datagrid and inside it there is MtListbox. I have set vertical scroll bar to auto, it is working fine but i need an option that whenever scroll bar appears it should go down and show the last item.

Answer (score 3):

`ScrollViewer` has a property which indicates the vertical size of the area which can be scrolled inside it, called `ScrollableHeight`.

To alter the offset position within the `ScrollViewer`, you should utilize the `ChangeView` method, which causes the `ScrollViewer` to load a new View based on the offsets and zoom factor specified.

> public bool ChangeView(Nullable horizontalOffset,
>   Nullable verticalOffset, Nullable zoomFactor)

Now you can simply utilize it like this:

```
myScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, myScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, null);
```

You will want to make sure that this executes on the UI thread, and to do so you can dispatch the work to the UI thread:

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    myScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, myScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, null);
});
```